# Running Chrome on Slackware

Tags: linux, google-chrome, packages, slackware

I am new to Slackware and most Linux distributions. I have properly installed the Chrome package, yet like most other packages, I do not think it created a binary for me to run; or at least I don't know where the package put it. I have found numerous tutorials online about how to install chrome from Slackware, but not a single one tells you how to run it after it is installed. Help would be much appreciated and I can provide any other information for solving this problem if necessary.

Comment: `/usr/lib/google-chrome/chrome`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How did you installed it?
2. How are you launching it?
3. What `whereis google-chrome` says?

If I were you I'd go to [SlackBuilds](http://slackbuilds.org/repository/13.0/network/google-chrome/), get the google chrome slackbuild, built it and installed package from /tmp/

Answer (score 1):

If you use the build script from [Slackbuilds.org](http://Slackbuilds.org), and install it afterwards, a menu item is automatically added to the menu in KDE under Internet.

BTW, if you don't use it, get and install [sbopkg](http://sbopkg.org/) to automatically build and install packages on Slackware.

Comment: I am using fluxbox as my de and nothing was added to to my internet selections.  I did try installing it from slackbuilds as well. I got both the source and the slack build neither seemed to work.

Comment: You can find instructions on adding items to fluxbox menu here: http://fluxbox-wiki.org/index.php?title=Editing_the_menu

Answer (score 0):

The slackpkg install script installs to the following directory:
**/opt/google/chrome/chrome**